# Kaehlerian metric on a tangent bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I am trying to construct a Kaehler structure on $R^{4}$ following paper of V. Oproiu, "Some new geometric structures on the tangent bundle".
This is how the author constructs a metric on a tangent bundle $TM$ of a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$.
We know that the Levi-Civita connection of $g$ defines a direct sum decomposition
\begin{align}
\notag
TTM=VTM \oplus HTM,
\end{align}
of the tangent bundle into the vertical distribution $VTM$ and the horizontal distribution $HTM$. The vector fields $(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^{1}},..,\frac{\partial}{\partial y^{n}})$ define a local frame field for $VTM$ and for $HTM$ we have the local frame field $(\frac{\delta}{\delta x^{1}},..,\frac{\delta}{\delta x^{n}})$, where
\begin{align}
\notag
\frac{\delta}{\delta x^{i}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}-\Gamma_{i0}^{h}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^{h}},
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\notag
\Gamma_{i0}^{h}=\Gamma_{ik}^{h}y^{k},
\end{align}
$\Gamma_{ik}^{h}$ are the Christoffel symbols defined by the Riemannian metric $g$.

(In my case, where $M=R^{4}$, $\frac{\delta}{\delta x^{i}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}$)

Next we consider the energy density
\begin{align}
t=\frac{1}{2}g_{ik}(x)y^{i}y^{k}.
\end{align}
Let $u$, $v$ be two real smooth functions. We shall assume that $u$, $u+2tv$ have positive values. Then we may consider the following symmetric $M$-tensor field of type $(0,2)$ on $TM$, defined by the components
\begin{align}
G_{ij}=u(t)g_{ij}+v(t)g_{0i}g_{0j},
\end{align}
where $g_{0i}=g_{hi}y^{h}$.
With,
\begin{align}
H^{kl}
\end{align}

we denote the coefficients of the inverse matrix of $(G_{ij})$.

We shall also use the components $H_{ij}$
\begin{align}
H_{ij}=g_{ik}H^{kl}g_{lj}
\end{align}

We use the followig $M$-tensor fields on $TM$
\begin{align}
G^{kl}=g^{ki}G_{ij}g^{jl}, G_{k}^{i}=G^{ih}g_{hk}, H_{k}^{i}=H^{ih}g_{hk}.
\end{align}
The following Riemannian manifold may be considered on $TM$
\begin{align}
\notag
G(\frac{\delta}{\delta x^{i}}, \frac{\delta}{\delta x^{j}})=G_{ij},
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\notag
G(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^{i}},\frac{\partial}{\partial y^{j}})=H_{ij},
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\notag
G(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^{i}},\frac{\delta}{\delta x^{j}})=G(\frac{\delta}{\delta x^{j}},\frac{\partial}{\partial y^{i}})=0.
\end{align}
An almost complex structure $J$ may be defined on $TM$ by
\begin{align}
J\frac{\delta}{\delta x^{i}}=G_{i}^{k}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^{k}},
\end{align}
\begin{align}
J\frac{\partial}{\partial y^{i}}=-H_{i}^{k}\frac{\delta}{\delta x^{k}}.
\end{align}
Then we have two theorems.
Theorem 1

$(TM, G, J)$ is an almost Kaehlerian manifold.

Theorem 2

$J$ is integrable if $(M,g)$ has constant sectional curvature $c$ and the function $v$ is given by 
\begin{align}
v=\frac{c-uu'}{2tu'-u}.
\end{align}

Using the calculation above, I obtained this for the metric on $R^{4}$.
\begin{align}
\notag
G = \left (\begin{array}{cccc}
 u+v(y^{1})^{2} & vy^{1}y^{2} & 0 & 0 \\
vy^{1}y^{2}& u+v(y^{2})^{2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \alpha  (u+v(y^{2})^{2})& -\alpha vy^{1}y^{2}\\
0 & 0 & -\alpha vy^{1}y^{2} & \alpha  (u+v(y^{2})^{1})
\end{array} \right )
\end{align},
where

\begin{align}
\notag
\alpha = \frac {1} {u^{2} + uv ((y^{1})^{2} + (y^{2})^{2})}
\end{align}

and this for $J$.

\begin{align}
\notag
J\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{1}} = (u+v(y^{1})^{2})\frac{\partial}{\partial y^{1}} + vy^{1}y^{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^{2}}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\notag
J\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{2}} = vy^{1}y^{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^{1}} + (u+v(y^{2})^{2})\frac{\partial}{\partial y^{2}}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\notag
J\frac{\partial}{\partial y^{1}} = -\alpha (u+v(y^{2})^{2})\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{1}} + \alpha vy^{1}y^{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{2}}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\notag
J\frac{\partial}{\partial y^{2}} = \alpha vy^{1}y^{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{1}} -\alpha (u+v(y^{1})^{2})\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{2}}
\end{align}

Then, by checking we obtain that $(R^{4}, G, J)$ is an almost Kaehler manifold, but not a Kaehler. Also, if I use Theorem 2 for obtaining $v$, there is a problem.

If we choose $u=(y^{1})^{2} + (y^{2})^{2}$, then according to Theorem 2, $v= -1$ and $u+2tv=0$.

Hope you can help me with this calculation and notice where the mistake is better then myself.

Thank you very much in advance.